# PHP - Using selected database element to fill up table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have a site project where multi-line CSV files are being uploaded and inserted to a database table. Once this is done, the user goes to the dashboard and can select certain values to pull up one of these work orders and display they info in a table. I created the tables and mapped the elements to the DB and on the user page I have select/drop down boxes filling properly from the database like so:

```
<label>Select Work Order Packet:</label>

<br>

<select name="place">
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT place FROM staging;");
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option >" . $row['place'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<br>

<label>OR</label>

<br>

<label>Select Work Order ID:</label>

<br>

<select name="WorkOrderNumber">

<?php

$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging;");
while($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option>" . $row2['workOrderNum'] . "</option>";
}
?>  

</select>
<br>
```

These fill up properly and I can select one but the next step has me confused. Once a value is selected, like work order number or serial number, I want to pull the entire record corresponding to that value from my staging table and place it in the html tables I've created on my display.php page. SO, when a value is selected from a drop down and submit is pressed, it will open the display.php page and fill the tables with the record corresponding to selected values. I just don't know how to reference those selected values when filling the tables.

Here is an example of one of the html tables from display.php:

```
<?
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
?>
<!--Qa Table-->
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Qa/Qc CheckList</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Address Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Loc Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

These values correspond, they just don't know what record from the database staging table to use.

Comment: Pull in the ID as well on that row...?

Comment: You mean in the select options? So pull in my primary key before the actual value in each select box? I think I know how to do that, but then when I do a submit button to post to display.php, how does it grab the correct record?

Comment: You have to pass `orderNumber` to display.php in $_POST or $_GET then on display.php retrieve that `orderNumber`, Query to database where `orderNumber = '$orderNumber'` and show the result.

Comment: Send the value with the form data, viz a viz: <?php echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>".$row['place']."</option>\n"; ?>